# Run SQL Command in Asp Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I want to write a value to a SQLite Database when I click on a button. How can I archive that? I found out how I can read data from a database using models, but not how to write data.

```
@model IEnumerable<Sooziales_Netzwerk.Models.Link>
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
String username = User.Identity?.Name;
if(User.IsInRole("verified")){
   username = username + "✓";
}
}

<div class="text-center">
@if(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome @username</h1>
}else 
{
    <h1 class="display-4">SavedThat</h1>
    <p>Link your Life up!</p>
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <script>
        function copyToClipboard(var linktext){
            window.clipboardData.setData('Text', linktext);
        }
    </script>
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.linkText)</h2>
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)</p>
    
    bool liked = false;
    var selectedQueryString = "UPDATE Link SET likes = 1 WHERE idLink = " + item.idLink;
    <button onclick=> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.likes)</button>
    <button onclick=copyToClipboard(@item.linkText)>Share</button>
}
```

This is my index.cshtml. I want to run the SQL Command in the variable selectedQueryString when clicked on the Button .

This is my HomeController.cs:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Sooziales_Netzwerk.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sooziales_Netzwerk.Data;

namespace Sooziales_Netzwerk.Controllers;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext _context;

/*public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}*/

public HomeController(Sooziales_NetzwerkDbContext context, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _context = context;
    _logger = logger;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Link.ToListAsync());
}

public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult TermsOfService()
{
    return View();
}

[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
}
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I guess you mean this line: `var selectedQueryString = "UPDATE Link SET likes = 1 WHERE idLink = " + item.idLink;` . I never heard of parameterised queries before so that is new to me. I tried to find something on google, but they are only using textboxes. I do not use textboxes. So how can I improve the code?